# How to retrieve / upload a schema to azure Schema Registry using an http client?

Tags: azure, avro, azure-eventhub

I am trying to upload and retrieve schemas from Azure Schema Registry programmatically.
It seems, that this can not be done with the Terraform resssource provider, and I would like the ability to upload schemas trough a pipeline.

I am authenticating, and sending the following curl to retrieve my schema group:

```
curl "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-event-hubs-cancellation-service-ab-dev/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/evh-ns-cancellation-service-ab-dev/schemagroups/schgp-cancellation-service-ab-dev?api-version=2022-10-01-preview" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat .ms_token)" | jq
```

And I am getting this response:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   586  100   586    0     0    308      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   309
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-event-hubs-cancellation-service-ab-dev/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/evh-ns-cancellation-service-ab-dev/schemagroups/schgp-cancellation-service-ab-dev",
  "name": "schgp-cancellation-service-ab-dev",
  "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/Namespaces/SchemaGroups",
  "location": "North Europe",
  "properties": {
    "updatedAtUtc": "2023-10-22T14:26:46.6092604Z",
    "createdAtUtc": "2023-10-22T14:26:46.6092604Z",
    "eTag": "9aa2d9dc-1d85-4595-a29f-fcdc166d7867",
    "groupProperties": {},
    "schemaCompatibility": "Forward",
    "schemaType": "Avro"
  }
}
```

Hover, I am stuck from here, there are no links to schemas, or child entities.
I tried to add '/schemas' and '/schema' to the URL path, but I am getting the following error:

```
"Resource Provider does not support any route matching the request URI. If this is a request for an entity with multi-segment names, encode '/' with '~' in the entity name."
```

Anyone that can point me how to retrieve / upload schemas from a HTTP client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as follows:
The [REST documentation for eventhubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-management-rest) lists, that the API is segregated into

- a control plane, with the REST endpoints that start with `management.core.windows.net`
- a data plane, with REST endpoints that start with `eventhubs.azure.net`

You can retrieve a schema group using a Management API endpoint, as written in the question:

```
curl "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/<your-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/<your-eventhub-namespace>/schemagroups/<your-schemagroup-name>?api-version=2022-10-01-preview" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

You can retrieve the list of schemas, by calling the data plane REST endpoint (here, using httpie)

```
https -a $TOKEN -A bearer "$BASE/\$schemagroups/<your-schemagroup-name>/schemas?api-version=2022-10"
```

where `BASE=https://<your-eventhub-namespace>.servicebus.windows.net`.

The thing, that fooled me was, that you need a different Bearer token for the Management endpoint, and a different Bearer token for the data plane endpoint.

A Bearer token can be obtained by the following call:

```
curl https://login.microsoftonline.com/$AZURE_TENANT_ID/oauth2/token \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AZURE_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET&resource=$RESOURCE"
```

where `RESOURCE=https://management.core.windows.net` for access to Management plane, and `RESOURCE=https://eventhubs.azure.net` for access to Data plane.